# Get a file from assets, read it and copy the contents in another file

Tags: android, android-assets

i am having a file in the assets folder. I want to open the file, read the byte[] through the `InputStream` and then use the `FileOutputStream` to write the byte[] into another file.

My code:

```
assetManager = MainActivity.this.getAssets();
                assetStream = assetManager.open("qamaster2.pfx");
                File file = StringGenerator.createFileFromInputStream(assetStream, "qamaster2.pfx");
```

and the method createFileFromInputStream:

```
public static File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) {

        try{
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Log.e("File", file.getName());
            if (file.exists()){
                int size = inputStream.available();
                Log.e("File size", String.valueOf(size));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                inputStream.read(buffer);
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return file;
        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "Something happened here");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

but still nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: but in your code you never "write" the input stream you got to a new file, how do you expect to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read file from asset like this

```
  try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("file name");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then create new file and write this InputStream to that file.

give read and write permission in manifest file .

write input stream to file like this  ------

```
 try {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                            "picture_G.jpg");
                    output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                    int read;

                    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    output.flush();


                } finally {
                    inputStream.close();
                    output.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // handle exception, define IOException and others
            }
```

Comment: i also want to create a file from this. the creation of the file is giving me trouble

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you can also create and write files in the local app filespace as follows (adapted from previous answer):

```
private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    try{
        File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "temp1.txt");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;

        while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        return f;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
}
```